# fasterxml jackson ClassCastException

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a small piece of code that is running in a IBM SCO BPMN block.
The code is using Jackson to map REST API responses (JSON) to objects... The problem is that the code is not always working (I could not figure out exactly what breaks it..)
I am getting

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy216 incompatible with com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.VisibilityChecker$Std.(VisibilityChecker.java:172)

Can you please give me a hint...
Thank you
Bogdan,

Comment: the stack trace is probably much longer... could you post the whole stack trace?  it'd give more insight.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the IBM environment, but what I could think of is the environment might have built-in Jackson 1.x and you are using Jackson 2.x. For Jackson version info, you may refer to [JacksonDownload](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDownload) page.